# Index-Small formula keeps repeating

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The excel formula that I'm using appears to be repeating the same results upon condition of only one value on my conditional formatting drop down list.  In this case, it repeats the results only for "Pacira Biosciences". How can I fix it to stop repeating the same results just like the other items on the drop down list?

**The formula is this:**

`=IFERROR(INDEX(RAW!$D$2:$D$279,SMALL(IF(RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5,ROW(RAW!$D$2:$D$279)-1,10^10),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Excel File can be seen/downloaded here on Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYw1ZX941yr2gVY0DOBd_YEGI1d9jmPG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just edited. I was wondering how can I fix it to stop repeating the same results just like the other items on the drop down list.

Comment: My version of Excel is 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(RAW!$D$2:$D$279,SMALL(IF(((RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5)*(IFERROR(MATCH(RAW!$D$2:$D$279,IF(RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5,RAW!$D$2:$D$279),0)=ROW(RAW!$D$2:$D$279)-1,FALSE))),(ROW(RAW!$B$2:$B$279)-1)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

---

If in the future you upgrade to OFFICE 365 then it gets much simpler:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(RAW!$D$2:$D$279,RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5))
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. It results in an empty blank cell even after arranging it as an array with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. The same goes for any other selection I choose in Cell C5

Comment: I assume then that you have blanks or errors in the range `RAW!$D$2:$D$279`?

Comment: Yes, there are blanks.

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much!